# Basic book on stochastic calculus, Itô and jump processes and Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, books, jump-diffusion

I was looking for a good book that explains at beginner-level the basic of stochastic calculus, probability and random variables, Itô and jump processes as well as Brownian Motion.

At university we are going really fast hence I need a book to go through the basics again.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi there, "jump, ito, brown" ... wouldn't you like to improve the title a bit? Are you interested in "jump processes" (e.g. Lévy-processes) or jump-diffusions? Brownian motion or Ito calculus?

Comment: Shreve is good for the less technically inclined reader (but more than what is required for hull eg). Then willmott then oksendal i would say

Answer (score 4):

The book **Stochastic calculus for finance** by Steven Shreve gives a good introduction to stochastic calculus applied to finance. A whole chapter is dedicated to the Itô Integral for example. It covers a large spectrum ranging from probability theory to stochastic financial models. I strongly recommend it!

Answer (score 4):

[*Elementary Stochastic Calculus*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Elementary-Stochastic-Calculus-Finance-View/dp/9810235437) by Thomas Mikosch is an excellent introduction to the topic in a very compact way. Alternatively, [*Stochastic Calculus for Finance II: Continuous-Time Models*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Stochastic-Calculus-Finance-Ii-Continuous-Time/dp/144192311X) by Steven Shreve is a more comprehensive reference which is very much oriented to applications in finance.

Answer (score 2):

Consider “Paul Wilmott Introduces Quantitative Finance” if you look for an enjoyable read, good intuition and a not too academic approach

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in learning about stochastic calculus outside of the context of quant finance (which I think is a better approach than learning about it solely in the context of finance), check out [Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783662026199?gclid=Cj0KCQiA-8PjBRCWARIsADc18TKIrdj1meq0bIMR-LWzd2o4u-kzwhLFEETSSAVuJrFZGvQoDs8sT5MaAqZ1EALw_wcB#otherversion=9783540509967) by Protter.